# Logical statement with 2 textboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a problem with my code when I am doing a logical statement with 2 textboxes.

I just want to check before I close my userform if Textbox4's value is smaller then the absolute of textbox6's value.

```
If Me.TextBox4.Value <= Abs(Me.TextBox6.Value) Then
 MyInput = MsgBox("Warning. The absolute max or min signal is bigger then Full Scale. Do you want to continue anyway?", vbYesNo)
```

(When testing the code the msgbox does not activate when textbox4.value is smaller right now.)

Am I missing something? Is this not the correct way to write it?

Thanks for any help.

Here is the full Code:

```
    Private Sub selectcmd1_Click()

   Dim MyInput
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Worksheets("InputS&T")


    If Me.TextBox4.Value <= Abs(Me.TextBox6.Value) Then
     MyInput = MsgBox("Warning. The absolute max or min signal is bigger then Full Scale. Do you want to continue anyway?", vbYesNo)

        If MyInput = vbYes Then

'find first empty row in database---------------------------------
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, searchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
Unload Me

    BeginRow = 13
    EndRow = 40
    ChkCol = 3

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "" Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt
'-------------------------------------------------------------
Else

End If

Else

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, searchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
Unload Me

    BeginRow = 13
    EndRow = 40
    ChkCol = 3

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "" Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: you are checking if it is smaller or equal

Comment: Yeah that is intended but it doesn't activate the the messegebox when I enter a smaller value or even equal at the moment

Comment: saying _It is not working right now.._ is not helpful information

Comment: put everything on one line , or use `end if`

Comment: Please post the rest of your `Sub`s relevant code

Comment: Thanks but Ive got the end if later in the coding. It doesn't give me any error message when running the code. It is just that it does not react when textbox4 is smaller then textbox 6

Comment: @JonathanAndersson - you need to convert the values to numeric to do a numeric comparison otherwise you are doing a text compare. If the values are real (i.e. not integers) then use `CDbl` on the textbox values per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the values to `Double` and then do the check:

```
Dim dblVar1 As Double
Dim dblVar2 As Double

dblVar1 = CDbl(Me.TextBox4.Value)
dblVar2 = CDbl(Me.TextBox6.Value)

If dblVar1 <= Abs(dblVar2) Then
    MyInput = MsgBox("Warning. The absolute max or min signal is bigger then Full Scale. Do you want to continue anyway?", vbYesNo)
End If
```

Reason is that whilst you can do something like this in VBA:

```
If "10" < "6" Then
    '...
End If
```

It won't give the expected result because `"10" < "6"` is `True` because it is a text comparison.

Comment: you went all the way to `CDbl`, maybe start with `Clng` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - Why ? Perhaps the values are real ? You are truncating the possible value if you use `CLng`. I disagree with the comment unless the OP states that the values are integer. Try `? CLng(1.2)` in your Immediate window...

Comment: Thanks alot @RobinMackenzie The code worked as intended!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
If CLng(Me.TextBox1.Value) <= CLng(Abs(Me.TextBox2.Value)) Then
```

instead of

```
If Me.TextBox4.Value <= Abs(Me.TextBox6.Value) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
Dim myinput As Variant

If Me.TextBox4.Value <= Abs(Me.TextBox6.Value) Then
    myinput = MsgBox("Warning. The absolute max or min signal is bigger then Full Scale. Do you want to continue anyway?", vbYesNo)
End If

If myinput <> vbYes Then Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried with Robins solution and it worked as intended. Appreciate it though!